# Why does JavaScript (or ECMAScript) not allow var(x)=1?

Tags: javascript

This might not be the most obvious question, but it seems to me that variable declaration has the only enforced semantic whitespace in JavaScript. Is this correct? You can avoid it in other constructs, like these.

```
new(XMLHTTPRequest)
typeof(x)
'a'in(x)
(a)in(x)
```

Comment: Because the spec says that parens don't make a valid token name.

Comment: @Raynos. He's asking why does it say it. It's more a [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) question more than StackOverflow question.

Comment: Parenthesis in any context other than function invocation and definition are just a way to enforce order of operations. They are also convenient for making things easier to read.

Comment: We can't define variables using symbols except $ and _ (underscore)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67defydd(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Might be so you won't think the variable name is `(x)` but `x` so you won't do things like that:

```
var (x) = "foo";
(x).indexOf('f')
```

But I think the best answer is:

That's the way they designed javascript. (And thanks God for this!)